# How to export from Org mode to HTML excluding all but <body> content?

Tags: org-export

Is there a way to export to HTML from Org mode without the extra content at the top of the document?

For example, is it possible to export only what would be inside the `<body>` tags and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using org-export `C-c C-e`, there's a menu that shows the export options (html, plain text, etc.). In that menu, there's an option `C-b` for *body only*. Toggle this, then export, and it will export just what's in `<body>`.